# How to show a webview progress bar at the bottom of the app?

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there a way to show, only while loading, a webview's progress bar, at the bottom of the app ?

Currently, my progress bar is showed in the title bar.  But I don't want it there.  I want it at the botton of the app.

Is there a way to do it ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to hide the title bar (not necessary but it will save screen space), and add your own progress bar at the bottom of your layout.

But it goes against the normal user interface standards and could be confusing to users so I wouldn't recommend to change the progress bar location.

Comment: Thanks LadaRaider,
I totally understand your point of view about the standards.  But if I show the progress bar only when it is used, it will be more user friendly...  I will try your suggestion and post the result in few minutes (or hours...!!).  Thanks!